# Is it feasible to use either Task.Run or BackgroundWorker to process multiple account registrations simultaneously

Tags: task, backgroundworker

Some background - I am using VB.Net for a fairly heavily loaded (with logic/functions) web service. The web service app is about 850kb and also calls a decent number of DLL's for other processing. It handles quite a few functions including Enrollment, Verification, Email verification, and a decent number of others (25+), some of which require a decent amount of processing before completion.

Running a dedicated Windows Server, 32Gb

I am concerned that with a large number of concurrent enrollments and verifications being called, the web service might choke.

I am thinking of splitting the app up somewhat so as to have at least enrollment, verification and email notices, in different web services but not sure if that will improve things, as once the bulk of enrollments are done the load will be on the verification process ongoing.

My question then is, regarding trying to speed up the processes and not have people queued up / delayed in their connections, would it make sense to take the "core" of the logic for enrollment, and the core of the logic for verification, and likewise email notices, and launch them in a separate Thread of sorts ?

I have read and seen a bit about Tasks and BackgroundWorker

Is there one or the other that would be best to use, and as I have described, is it worth doing ?

Thanks

Comment: "*might choke*" - Is the problem even real? Or are you prematurely optimizing?

Comment: You should probably always use task async pattern to do IO in .net, btw

Comment: "prematurely"   Yes, perhaps being overcautious.
Task it is then, thanks